# Xamarin Android - Exception when calling Environment.GetExternalStorageState(File path)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I’m unable to use the `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState` **method** as [outlined here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState/).

The `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStorageState` **property** works. However in order to query the state the secondary external SD card’s state I need to use the **method** (not the **property**) and pass in the path to the secondary external SD card. When calling this method I receive a .NET exception as follows:

> No static method with name=’getExternalStorageState’
>   signature=’(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/lang/String;’ in class
>   Landroid/os/Environment;

A sample app that reliably reproduces the problem [can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4wprqhnfiw8rdp/ExternalStorageStateTest.zip?dl=0).

Note that this is on a device that has 2 SD cards. One is internal (not removable) and is the default SD card path. The other SD card is an external SD card which is removable. This test app assumes the external secondary removable SD card is at a root path of ‘sdcard1’ and the default internal is ‘sdcard0’. You may need to change this if your device is different.

Here is a trimmed down version of the CheckState from the sample app.

```
private bool CheckState(string pathStr) 
{
   try
     {
        var path = new File(pathStr);

        var otherState = Environment.ExternalStorageState;

        var state = Environment.GetExternalStorageState(path);

        // Good state - set values and be done
        return state.Equals(Environment.MediaMounted);

      }
    catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
      {
          Debug(Tag, $"Java Ex: {ex.Message}");
      }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Debug(Tag, $".Net Ex: {ex.Message}");
      }
    return false;
}
```

In the example code above, the `otherState` variable is set with the state of the internal SD card. However when the next line with the `state` variable executes an exception is thrown.

Also, as an FYI - it is the .Net `System.Exception` that is thrown, no the `Java.Lang.Exception`.

If this code is correct and there is in fact a bug in the framework code somewhere (Xamarin and/or Android) then is there a recommended work around to determine if an SD card is available for reading & writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No static method with name=’getExternalStorageState’ signature=’(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/lang/String;’ in class Landroid/os/Environment;

`String getExternalStorageState (File path)` was added in **API 21**.

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)

Comment: That explains it - We're running KitKat

Comment: @Steve Xamarin's docs have the wrong API level listed in this case, I tend to use Google's doc as I know they are correct ;-) Do a API level check and if <21 you can use `GetStorageState(File path)` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getStorageState(java.io.File)